# problem with JS comparison logic if/and/or

Tags: javascript

so here is the scenario

```
if ( ( a >= b) && ( (c < d) && (d != '') ) )
```

cannot get this logic on this to work correctly

so if d = '' it would cause that to be false. which would mean that the whole thing would equate to false. Problem is I need it to trigger when a >= b but also needs to include the and for c < d but only if d != '', in other words ignore the c < d part if d = '', otherwise used the c < d part to prevent a >= b from triggering.

hope this is making sense. I am trying to avoid doing and if/else or switch.

Comment: Then you need OR instead of AND.

Comment: if ( ( a >= b) && (  (d != '') || (c < d)  ) )

Comment: `if (a >= b && (d == '' || c < d))`

Comment: This actually made my brain hurt, but I think this will work: `if((d != '' && (a >= b && c< d)) || a >= b)`

Comment: I think if you had a clearer problem description we could help better. By the way that would be the same thing to code needed anyways. There are blind spots.

Answer (score 0):

One comment would be if you are not absolutely avoid using if/else or switch then you could define funcitons use them and use thiss functions in your statement above.

Apart from that, changing the order of some expressions might do what you want. `c < d` would not be evaluated if `d = ''` is not `true`. `a >= b` would not be evaluated if the expresion before second or, `||`, is `true` or `d == ''`, empty string, is `true`.

```
if ((d != '' && c < d) || (d != '' && c >= d && a >= b))
```

which is;

```
if (d != '' && (c < d || a >= b))
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to evaluate the `a >= b`-part **regardless** of the value of `d`. The `c < d`-part must additionally evaluate to true - **but only if** `d != ''`.

Comment: Thanks. I will consider this. But I think, in those cases, the OP usually does not know what OP wants OPself :D. I do not say this in a pejorative sense. I mean it and I mean it for good. Or one can say OP cannot say to OPself what OP wants.

Comment: non OPs does not. Otherwise many professional programmers would very probably solve such a basic logic problem even in a particular way of coding like costraining it to sue if else or switch. But good for you if you feel ok for what you know for that problem.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your suggestions, I found a workaround though
I just put

```
if (d == '') { d = Infinity; }
```

then

```
if ( (a >= b) && (c < d) )
```

and that solved it

thanks for everyone's help

Comment: think someone woke up an the wrong side of the bed. Just didn't want people to spend more time on it, the workaround will do it for now. There was probably a flaw in my original logic anyway. If ands and ors produced same result, I must have screwed something up.

Comment: It was a jokeful comment on a previous edit of yours it did not even have code formatting. Nothing about me.

Comment: anyways thanks for trying, it was a serious stupidity on my part, as I have been programming the last 12 hours strait and it is all starting to look the same, seeing a's and b's everywhere at this point. Would be curious to see if someone ever wants to try to solve the original logic, but the more I think about it, probably never would have evaluated to a TRUE if d = '' the way it was written.

Comment: You are very welcome. Sorry to hear about that. My only intention is try to help and keep it fun for myself, well not necessarily not-fun for others too. I still have concerns about question. But if you want to close the case go for it, you might have solved the question even it is for practicality. Come back anytime. Cheers.